# Module not found in Pandas UDF for multi-node

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I am trying to run a pandas udf function in jupyter notebook where I want to import some module I wrote in this pandas udf. The code can be ran through in local mode. But when I try to run it in multi-node. It shows the model is not found in other executors.

Without pandas udf, I can import the module on multi-node. So, I think this is some issue related to pandas udf.

Anyone has similar problem before? Any solution?

Below is my code in Jupyter notebook:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
from pyspark.sql.types import *
schema_return=spark_df.schema
@pandas_udf(schema_return, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def scoring_pudf(snap_df):
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import re
    import pyarrow.parquet as pq
    from datetime import datetime, date
    from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
    import time

    import config as conf
    from econ import EconData


    #initialize & read in configration file
    config = conf.DevConfig()

    #initialize & read in econ data
    econ = EconData(config)

    return econ
```

The error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
```